# How to discretize value like EDF ( or other electricity companie )

Tags: standard, time

I make a solution using some automate like : A9MEM2050 ( Shneider )
( and more advanced, so i have a lot a different value , that include rpm, psi, armonic, etc ...)

Every automate send a value every 10 minutes

Some 'intensive' data: 
[image]
Some 'extensive' data:
[image]

My question is about the discretization ...
I want to display a some chart displaying a value every hours, days, month, years ...

( for simplify the question we only care about the discretisation from 10 minutes to 1hours )

So, simple if data is 'intensive' i make a mean, if data is 'extensif' i return the last value minus the first value ...

But the value at 1:00 is calculate with ( for a 'intensive' ) the value at :
    [00:10, 00:20, 00:30, 00:40, 00:50, 1:OO]
or
    [01:00, 01:10, 01:20, 01:30, 01:40, 01:5O]

Can you provide a RFC / ISO or other Scientific paper on the subject ?

---- Info : 
The boss of my companie say : 
 - Shneider customer service say, the agregator take a instant value, no Math is done internaly ... 
 - 'El-sys GTC' have a option in their firmware and let us the choice
 - 'Carel' no info provide the companie :/

Answer (score 0):

- Energy meters measure *energy* in kilowatt-hours (kWh). They do not measure power.
- The energy meter will count the number of kWh used in the measuring period. This could be 15 minutes, 30 minutes or one hour.
- Usually the kWh count is a total count. That means that energy used for an period is given by \$ energy = reading_{end} - reading_{start}\$.
- If you only have a power meter then you have to assume the power remains constant for the time period and just multiply kW × hours.

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical energy meter reading graph.*

> When I say *i* have use X Watt of power at 6:00 AM ... I have to use the value between 5 AM and 6 AM or value between 6 AM and 7 AM?

Again, you need to measure *energy*, not power. The reading will be taken at the end of the measuring period. Now it is up to you how to present this. Think of how you will present the daily readings. You want all the hourly readings for yesterday so you can do:

```
Period starting    Energy (kWh)
00:00              00207
01:00              00302
...
23:00              00509
```

Or you could do period ending but then you end with a time 24:00 which does not exist. I think "period starting" is better.

> Can you provide a RFC / ISO or other Scientific paper on the subject?

No. Why would you need one?

> This equipement return a value already discritised at 10 minutes ... but internaly he work lot faster thant every 10 minutes ... So how he discritise the value internaly?

[image]

*Figure 2. An old-fashioned energymeter just counts up continuously using a spinning disk. A modern digital meter will integrate power by time to count the energy used.*

> The point a 00:10 on my csv is the value from 00:00 to 00:10 or value from 00:10 to 00:20? I want a official document about this, i didn't think every constructor choice by flipping a coin.

The answer to those questions will be in the energy meter and datalogger manuals. You may need to check with whoever configured them during installation.

Comment: Thank for your answere... i'm not in charge of mesurement, i juste work on the 'display' part of the project ...
So i have a lot of csv files with a value every 10 minutes ... i juste need to discretise the value ( so apply a sum or mean ... ) but when a customer say : give me the temperature or wathever at 6AM ... so i have to send the value between 5 and 6 or 6 and 7 ?

Comment: Are your numbers always increasing like in my Figure 1? If so you just use the step differences. Can you post a picture of a few rows of data in your question?

Comment: Yes my value look like this ( but i have other type of value too, temperature / rpm / pression ...  intensif or extentive value ) 
The value is mesured by equipement like IEM3100(  from schneider )
This equipement return a value already discritised  at 10 minutes ...
but internaly he work lot faster thant every 10 minutes ...

So how he discritise the value internaly ? ( the point a 00:10 on my csv is the value from 00:00 to 00:10 or value from 00:10 to 00:20 ? )

I want a official document about this, i didn't think every constructor choice by flipping a coin ...

Comment: ('Sheinder' customer service contacted by my boss say the equipement take a instante value, si no math is donne internaly ... 'El-sys GTC' ( another campanie ) the software let us the choice  ... and no info provide by  'Carel' companie )

Comment: @Andrelec1 You will see both hour ending and hour starting data in the industry.  If your customer asks for data at 6am you will have to ask them if *they* want hour starting or hour ending.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: @scorpdaddy I was afraid of having this answer.
So no standard, ask to the final client or flip a coin :/